# Pronom de reprise/rappel in declarative sentences

Tags: pronom-de-reprise

I  sometimes see declarative sentences using the ”pronom de rappel” like this:

> Aussi, sous le règne du nihilisme, la philosophie a-t-**elle** pour
> mobiles des sentiments noirs. (Nietzsche par Gilles Deleuze)

What’s the rôle of ”elle” here?

Comment: Do you already have a source where you find the name "pronom de rappel" ? For me it's a construction linked to some connnection words like *Aussi*, *ainsi*.

Comment: Nope, I just saw that phrase for the first time, while searching around for related questions here on this forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called *Inversion du sujet*.

It may happen also after encore, peut-être, sans doute.

See here https://cnrtl.fr/definition/aussi :

> **Aussi (adv de phrase)**
>
> Figure généralement en tête de phrase et entraîne le plus souvent l'inversion du sujet.
>
> (...) Synon. c'est pourquoi, en conséquence
>
> ex: Aussi oppose-t-on à la théologie naturelle ou rationnelle les religions positives